# USB Driver for Windows

Tags: windows, drivers

I want to make a usb driver in c for windows.  I have good background in c and c++.
Can anybody suggest me how should i start my development?any suggestion?

Comment: Open VS, start Googling.  But more seriously, you're probably better off starting with (re)searching on [StackOverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com).  As-is, your question is WAY to broad. :)

Comment: I searched in stack overflow but i didn't find.Can you please tell me how should i start?

Comment: You may want to start by defining your goal better than "make a usb driver in c for windows", as that doesn't really mean anything (to me at least). Anyhow a quick search of SO turned up these (and MANY others): [How do I program a driver for a USB device for windows platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161273/how-do-i-program-a-driver-for-a-usb-device-for-windows-platform?rq=1), and [Custom USB device driver, Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968673/custom-usb-device-driver-windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by downloading and checking the documentation for the WDK here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx

then perhaps check out the MS DDK Solution center here:
http://support.microsoft.com/ph/7229

and then mabey a tutorial or two:
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/24166-windows-driver-development-tutorial/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-1-Introduction-to-Drivers